# Cannot resolve symbol "FormBody" - okttp3 error

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using `okhttp3` to connect my android application to my `mysql` database but it gives me an error while using `FormBody.Builder()` (I see other using this method).

**I need to execute a post request.**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

     RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder() //this FormBody gives "Cannot resolve symbol FormBody"
            .add("name", reg_name)
            .add("pass", reg_pass)
            .build();

     Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(reg_url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```

Comment: Are you adding the import?  ->  `import okhttp3.FormBody;`   Does the import statement have an error as well?

Comment: @CzarMatt usually it tells me when he need an import but now he dont say anything.

Comment: I got these import:  com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;

Comment: Please add the import yourself and see if the object resolves.

Comment: Importing  okhttp3.FormBody; gives error, even using com.squareup.okhttp.FormBody;

Comment: In build gradle i've added "compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'"

Comment: Well, then that is your problem.  You said in your post that you are using okhttp3.  What you have there is not okhttp3.  You need to use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'`

Comment: Yep thats work, thank you @CzarMatt  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong version of okhttp.  Make sure your Gradle dependency is specified as follows:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
```

(or most appropriate version number)

Also, be sure to include the appropriate import statement:

```
import okhttp3.FormBody;
```